# Understanding matrix norms and spectral radius

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

I thought I understood matrix norms and spectral radius after reading proof of $||A||\geq \rho(A)$. However, in the lecture notes I'm given the following line, and asked what is wrong with the reasoning?

$$
|\lambda|||x||=||\lambda x||=||A x|| \leq ||A||\  ||x||
$$
Now, I suspect the part $||\lambda x|| = ||Ax||$ to be wrong, however, the notes aren't giving a definite answer. Could someone point me in the right direction or try explain what I'm looking for?

First we are given the statement that $||A||\geq\rho(A)$ followed by a proof where $x$ is a eigenvector of A associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$. We are given a proof utilizing norms from 
$$
A(xy^T)=(Ax)y^T=\lambda (xy^T)
$$
where $y \in C^n$ to arrive at the definition $|\lambda| \leq ||A||$ and since its true for every eigenvalue of A, we also get $\rho(A)\leq ||A||$.

Then the following appears after the proof (note the etc. at the end):

*Question to the reader:* What is wrong with the following line of reasoning
$|\lambda|\ ||x||=||\lambda x||=||A x|| \leq ||A||\  ||x||$ etc.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ an eigenvalue for $A$?

Comment: @Norse Yes, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue vector of the corresponding matrix $A$

Comment: Yeah, $\lambda x = Ax$ only when $x$ is an eigenvector, so you are right, we don't in general have $\Vert \lambda x \Vert= \Vert Ax\Vert$

Comment: @Norse The notes are a bit cryptic about it, but I do think $x$ is in fact the eigenvector and $\lambda$ are the corresponding eigenvalues, or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: But if $x$ is an eigenvector, then by definition you have $\lambda x = Ax$ and so they must have the same norm.

Comment: @Norse So the only mistake that exist in this line is that (possibly) I have made no assumption about the vector $x$?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yeah. Maybe if you show the whole paragraph, I can spot the mistake, if any

Comment: @Norse Updated with some more information from the same section. The proof is rather long, but it's mainly using norms to prove the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it more clear: Let's denote the eigenvektor by $y$, then we have:

$$|\lambda|||y||=||A y||$$ hence we get $$|\lambda| = \frac{||Ay||}{||y||} \le \sup_{||x|| \not= 0}\frac{||Ax||}{||x||} = ||A||$$

Multiplying with ||x|| gives the result.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with the line of reasoning? I'm confused... Either I'm not quite understanding the problem or the "problem" is just poorly written.

Comment: It's poorly written and mixes assumptions.
Let's comment each step:

$$|\lambda|\ ||x||\underbrace{=}_{\text{true for all x}}||\lambda x||\underbrace{=}_{\text{true for eigenvectors only}}||A x|| \underbrace{\leq}_{\text{true for all x}} ||A||\  ||x||$$

But although there is one step which holds for eigenvectors only the final inequality holds for all $x$ as shown in my post. 
To make it valid for all $x$ it should be noted as $$|\lambda|\ ||x||=||\lambda x|| \leq ||A||\  ||x||$$